# Semi Circle marker in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

Dears,

I created a semi circle in leaflet and I have three semi circles on the same latitude and longitue each one with different angel.
I just want to add a min circle or icon or marker or whatever inside each semi circle (in the center of semi circle).

does anyone have any idea how to do that please ?

```
    var $html = $(L.HTMLUtils.buildTable(record));

    var circle =  L.semiCircle(latLng, L.extend({
        radius: 70,
        renderer: canvas,
        weight: 1
    }, options)).bindTooltip(metaData).bindPopup($html.wrap('<div/>').parent().html(), {
        minWidth: 400,
        maxWidth: 400
    });

    circle.addTo(mymap);
    debugger;

    var circleBounds = circle.getBounds();

    var center = circleBounds.getCenter(),
        neCoord = circleBounds.getNorthEast(),
        northCenterCoord = new L.LatLng(center.lat, neCoord.lng, true);

    //debugger;

    var icon = L.divIcon({
        html: '<div class="txt">' + 'tessst' + '</div>',
        className: 'circle-with-txt',
        iconSize: [40, 40]
    });
    //var circle = L.circleMarker(latLng, options);
    var marker = L.marker(northCenterCoord, {
        icon: icon
    });
    var group = L.layerGroup([circle, marker]);
    group.addTo(mymap);
```

Regards,

Comment: Get the center of the semi Circle and add a circlemarker on this point to the map: `L.circleMarker(latlng, {radius: 10}).addTo(map)`

Comment: how to get the center of the semi circle, i cant got it?

Comment: you need to share your code and the library else we can't help ...

Comment: @FalkeDesign I edited the question above, Can you please check it (code has been added above).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the center of the semi circle with `circle.getLatLng()`

To add a small circlemarker call `L.circleMarker(circle.getLatLng(), {radius: 10}).addTo(map)`

Comment: This will add the circle on the same center of the first circle, i want to draw it in the middle between center of the main circle and radius.